# React Promise Return Firebase Array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I am having a really hard time solving this issue I'm currently having. You see, I am using Firebase as my database to store and fetch data.

Right now, I want to be able to return an array that is being made inside a Firebase .once call, but I am having some difficulties. This is my code so far:

Calling the function (a return function):

```
<p>{this.fetchStartingPrice(singleProduct.id)}</p>
```

This is where I want to display the specific value, that I am trying to fetch down below:

```
fetchStartingPrice(category){
        let promises = [];

        promises.push(this.fetchPrices(category));

        Promise.all(promises).then(result => {
            console.log(result);
        })
    }
```

I have just used a console.log in an attempt to troubleshoot errors.

```
fetchPrices(category){
        var allPrices = [];
         allProductsFirebase.child(category).once('value', (snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
                if(childSnapshot.key == category){
                    allPrices.append(childSnapshot.val().brand);
                }
            });
            return allPrices;
        })
    }
```

So basically, I want to loop through the allProductsFirebase in an attempt to first identify the brand of the product, and if it matches with the brand that has been used as a parameter in `fetchStartingPrice(`) and fetchPrises(), I want to store the specific price of that product in an array of numbers (prices). After I have looped through the whole snapshot, I want to return the full array containing only product prices, and then through `fetchStartingPrice()`, I want to use `Math.min(promises)` to grab the lowest number in that array. However, I am having a really hard time doing this. Could someone please help me with this?

I want to be able to then, after all of this, return the value in `fetchStartingPrice()`.

Answer (score 0):

`fetchPrices()` must return `Promise` or be `Promise`. you are returning nothing from `fetchPrices()` ( you are returning `allPrices` in the `.once()` scope ). try to return the result ( if it returns `Promise` ) that `.once()` returns.

```
fetchPrices(category){
    var allPrices = [];
     return allProductsFirebase.child(category).once('value', (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
            if(childSnapshot.key == category){
                allPrices.append(childSnapshot.val().brand);
            }
        });
        return allPrices;
    })

}
```

Comment: [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) `Promise.all` takes an array of promises as an argument. But you are putting an array of `undefined`s.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, deebov. However, I did in fact also try this method as well, but the thing is; it only returns a DataSnapshot when i Print the result in fetchStartingPrice(). Do you happen to know the solution for this?

Comment: look, I have had similar problems with it. I am building ecommerce app. But I use Firestore instead. Because with it I can better work with the data. If it returns DataSnapshot, you can get the data by calling `DataSnapshot.data()`. This returns the real data

Comment: I see. Is there any way I can avoid using Firestore? I am 99,9 percent finished with an ecommerce solution that I've spent 3 months developing, and switching to Firestore is unfortunately not an option at this moment. But thanks for the information, though. I appreciate it.

Comment: bro I think I found it. here is what you need https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot.

Comment: Hmm, I really can't seem to find out where tho?

Comment: you can get `DataSnapshot`'s value by its methof `.val()`. e.g. `DataSnapshot.val()`